# Delete all words surrounded by parentheses with sed

Tags: text-processing, sed

How can I do this in `sed`, I have a long long list of things and some are surrounded by a parentheses.

```
lol
xml
lol
lol (347)
idiot (67)
```

How can delete `(347)` and `(67)` but for a huge list with numbers and random letters in parentheses?

I tried this command, `sed 's/(*)/hshshshshs/g'` but I'm new to `sed`.

I was going to just use a  text editor to replace `hshshshshs` with nothing, as I wasn't sure `sed` could handle empty lines..

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
$ sed -e 's/([^()]*)//g'
```

Or you can use Perl:

```
$ perl -pe 's/\(.*?\)//g'
```

Comment: Careful, though. This assumes parentheses do not nest.

Answer (score -1):

The `*` means repeat the previous character zero or more times. Try adding a `.` which matches any character: `sed's/(.*)/hshshshshs/g`

Comment: That would replace `a (b) c (d) e` with `a hshshshshs e`